# How can I toggle two classes in two divs in pure javascript?

Tags: jquery, jackson

I have a card that reverses on click, I'm using jQuery, but i need to achieve this effect on pure javascript, I've searched another questions, but didn't find accurate solution, here is my html part:

```
 <div class="card">
    <div class="front"><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="back"><img src="2.jpg" alt=""></div>
 </div>
```

And css:

```
.card {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 1000px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: 1s;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.back  {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And finally jquery part:

```
 $('.card').click( function(){
$('.front, .back').toggleClass('back front');
});
```

I've tried different pure js solutions but only achieved toggling only front to back class, and my goal is to switch front to back and vice versa simultaneously.
Thank you for help.

Comment: You can use `querySelector()` to retrieve the elements, `addEventListener()` to attach the event handler then finally `classList.toggle()` to change the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Element.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
      ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
        el.classList.toggle(s)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="front">Front</div>
  <div class="back">Back</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect solution